# What can I do to avoid naming all functions using foreach

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

Hello I am using the `%dopar%` parallel functionality of the `foreach` package (`parallel` as the backend)
I have a line of code like this

```
exportedFn <- #STUFF
exportedPkg <- #STUFF
allDataT <- foreach(myFile=orderFiles, .combine='rbind', .packages=exportedPkg, .export=exportedFn) %dopar% getSetOrderData(myFile, f.type="SUBMIT");
```

The problem is that `getSetOrderData` calls differnet functions, those functions themselves call functions. It looks like I have to specify ALL SUBFUNCTIONS...

Is there a way for me to avoid doing this ?

Comment: Put all functions in a package?

Comment: :) come'on @Rolland  doing this is a lot of work, surely there is something simpler like exporting an environment or...

Comment: Where are these functions defined?  Presumably not packages, because you're handling them via "exportedPkg".  Are they all in `.GlobalEnv`, or somewhere else?

Comment: Hello @SteveWeston, they are defined in the same script, so they are in .GlobalEnv, yes. Additionally I had to export a global variable (assigned by <<-), I would have guessed it would be known everywhere too

Comment: If `foreach` is executed from .GlobalEnv and `getSetOrderData` is defined in `.GlobalEnv`, then any functions called by `getSetOrderData` that are also defined in `.GlobalEnv` should be auto-exported, as @SimonO101 said.  If not, then it sounds like a bug to me.  Could you post a reproducible example?

Comment: No, I might have misunderstood, thought you were refering about functions called by getSetOrderData, foreach itself is not executed from .GlobalEnv but inside a function. The functions called by getSetOrderData are function defined at top level in the script

Comment: @statquant in that case can you use `eval( foreachcode , envir = .GobalEnv )` to force `foreach`to be evaluated in the `.GlobalEnv`. I am sure there are a lot of good reason as to *why* you should not do this, but as a first step to see if you can get it running maybe you should try it?

Comment: @SimonO101: thanks but I think your other answer is better, I just have to source, so I already have a working solution (yours)

Comment: Well try it, if it works then it works! :-) But if it doesn't then try using `eval()` and let us know what happens. Does the source method work for you then? If so we could mark this question as closed ? Because I am still under the impression that solution is not satisfactory for your need?

Comment: I was hoping for a trick from @Steve Weston but it works, closed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure all variables are defined in the same environment as `getSetOrderData`? I find that if I define

```
fsub <- function( x ){
  return( x^2 )
}

fmain <- function( x ){
  x <- fsub( x ) + 2
  return(x)
}
```

And then I use them thus:

```
require(doParallel)
cl <- makeCluster( 2 , outfile = "" )
registerDoParallel( cl )
foreach( k = 1:2 , .verbose = TRUE , .combine = c ) %dopar%{
  fmain( k )
}
```

I get results as I expected:

```
numValues: 2, numResults: 0, stopped: TRUE
automatically exporting the following variables from the local environment:
  fmain, fsub 
got results for task 1
numValues: 2, numResults: 1, stopped: TRUE
returning status FALSE
got results for task 2
numValues: 2, numResults: 2, stopped: TRUE
first call to combine function
evaluating call object to combine results:
  fun(result.1, result.2)
returning status TRUE
[1] 3 6
```

And further, if I call the functions - which are not otherwise defined inside the `.GlobalEnv`- inside another function using `source()` it still works. Let's say I make a script called `util_funcs.R` inside my home directory and paste those two functions in, but call them `fsub2` and `fmain2`. If I call it in the following way:

```
fsource <- function( x ){
  source( "~/util_funcs.R" )
  x <- fmain2( x )
  return( x )
}
```

It still works:

```
numValues: 2, numResults: 0, stopped: TRUE
automatically exporting the following variables from the local environment:
  fsource 
got results for task 1
numValues: 2, numResults: 1, stopped: TRUE
returning status FALSE
got results for task 2
numValues: 2, numResults: 2, stopped: TRUE
first call to combine function
evaluating call object to combine results:
  fun(result.1, result.2)
returning status TRUE
[1] 3 6
```

Can you just copy/paste all the functions in a simple R script and use `source()`?

Comment: Rather than calling `source` from the task function (which may be called many times), I would initialize the workers with `clusterEvalQ(cl,source("~/util_funcs.R"))`.  It's more efficient and the functions are available for any number of `foreach` loops.